# Video Networkstate InternetExplorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video

I'm trying to create a video with slides next to it using HTML5 and Javascript.
The problem with InternetExplorer is that it's video networkstate stays on 2 for a while. As long as it is downloading the video, it won't be downloading my slides next to the video. 
As a fix I tried pausing the video if the preloaded image isn't loaded on the time it has to pick over the slides' spot. But however the video stays downloading (Taking about 300 seconds according to the network state) And once it's done the slides will load directly. (Taking 260 seconds according to the same thing, but as soon as the video is loaded they ARE loaded)

When ever I try to use myVideo.networkState in the console I get state 2(loading) when it's not working, and state 1 when it does. So it has something to do with the video.

So the question: 
Is there a way to either give priority to the slides, so they WILL load
Or a way to let IE download both slides and video on the same time.
Or giving the video a limited speed, if this has to do with a speed problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Delete Internet Explorer, Download Google Chrome.